# Accessing variable in an each loop javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I appreciate this is a common issue, but I'm new to JavaScript/JQuery and I can't work it out. I'm in a .each loop creating a new polygon in a google map and while I'm correctly able to access my polygon data as I iterate the model I get the same value for the colour. Polygon colour is always green.

This is kind of expected as I know there is an issue with scoping/loops/closures in JavaScript but I don't understand why I get one here and not the other.

```
var model = {
    crags: [{
        name: "Stanage",
        cragColor: "'#FF0000'",
        coords: [new google.maps.LatLng(53.360470, -1.646050),
        new google.maps.LatLng(53.359523, -1.647895),
        new google.maps.LatLng(53.351006, -1.637123),
        new google.maps.LatLng(53.351364, -1.627167)]
    }, {
        name: "Burbage",
        cragColor: "'#00AA00'",
        coords: [new google.maps.LatLng(53.341489, -1.606224),
        new google.maps.LatLng(53.338148, -1.605190),
        new google.maps.LatLng(53.338145, -1.600849),
        new google.maps.LatLng(53.341501, -1.604020)]
    }, {
        name: "Higgar",
        cragColor: "'#0000BB'",
        coords: [new google.maps.LatLng(53.340912, -1.611288),
        new google.maps.LatLng(53.338048, -1.612833),
        new google.maps.LatLng(53.339762, -1.608670)]
    }]
}

getCragName: function (index) {
    return model.crags[index].name;
}

$.each(controller.getCrags(), function (index, value) {
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: value.coords,
        strokeColor: value.cragColor,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: value.cragColor,
        fillOpacity: 0.35
    });
    polygons.push(polygon);
    polygon.setMap(map);
});
```

The full code can be found in this jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/erskmcha/

Comment: What's the behavior you're seeing, what's the behavior you *expect*, and how do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not due to scoping or closures, but is instead because you 'double-wrapped' the strings in the colour property:

```
cragColor: "'#FF0000'",
```

Should be:

```
cragColor: "#FF0000",
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/erskmcha/2/)

Comment: So, nothing whatsoever to do with variable access, closures... :-)

Comment: Nope. I was looking for a closure issue too until I saw the fiddle :)

Comment: Ah thanks - I've spent the last day reading about scope and so assumed the problem must be related to that - can't see wood for trees! Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Real simple to resolve. You have extra ' that does the damage.

Change:

```
    cragColor: "'#0000BB'",
```

To:

```
    cragColor: "#0000BB",
```

And you are done